# How to retrieve serialized data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

In a Rails 3.2 app I have a Model with a text column `:data`. In the model I have:

```
class Model
  serialize :data, Hash
end
```

This is storing data correctly, in the format `data:{"attr1"=>"foo", "attr2"=>"bar"....}`.

If I want to display this in a show view I can do `<%= @model.data %>`, and the entire hash is rendered.

But what if I only need to render a specific attribute? Is this possible?

I've tried several approaches that seemed like they might work:

`<%= @model.data.attr1 %>` - generates `undefined method 'attr1'`
`<%- @model.data[:attr1] %>` - displays nothing

Am I missing something? 
.
Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<%- @model.data[:attr1] %>
```

Replace with:

```
<%= @model.data["attr1"] %>
```

NOTE: `<%=` at the beginning. You've used `<%-` mistakenly.

**UPD:**

I recommend to use the `HashWithIndifferentAccess`:

```
serialize :data, HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

This way you can fetch your values via symbols or strings as the key.

Comment: doh! that makes sense. thanks! Can you recommend any good information about HashWithIndifferentAccess? From my searches it doesn't seem very well covered. Is it quite widely used, or likely to be deprecated? I like the ease of syntax, but don't want to be left high and dry :)

Comment: There isn't much to explain as this class has `Hash` as it's parent and allows you to use symbols instead of keys. But this class is EXTENSIVELY used by Rails. Even more: ActiveSupport adds method `with_indifferent_access` to the `Hash` itself to return `HashWithIndifferentAccess` instance. Try to put `<%= params.class %>` in any of your view and see yourself that I'm not joking )

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the string format of Hash key?

```
 @model.data['attr1']
```

Comment: Thanks Suborx, I should have tried this, but hadn't! I awarded the answer to jdoe for the extra serialization info, but have an up mark.

Comment: Thanks guys, I also mark up the jdoes answer right after i spotted.  And now +1 for question. ;)